# What can I wrap ListView. builder in?

Tags: flutter, dart

My problem is that I do not know what to wrap my `ListView.builder` in. By default, `ListView.builder` takes up the entire screen area, and I need to install a search bar or any other widget on top of this widget. This list works well if there are not many items in it. But when the elements become more than 1000, the application starts to slow down terribly.

My attempt to place elements in SingleChildScrollView:

```
class Body extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            SizedBox(height: getProportionateScreenHeight(10)),
            ProductHeader(),
            SizedBox(height: getProportionateScreenHeight(20)),
            Product()
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

class `Product`:

```
class Product extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetX<ProductController>(
      init: ProductController(),
      builder: (controller) {
        return FutureBuilder<List<ProductsCombined>>(
          future: controller.filterProduct.value,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return ListView.builder(
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                    ProductCards(
                  // index: index,
                  product: snapshot.data[index],
                ),
              );
            } else {
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            }
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

My attempt to place items in `CustomScrollView`:

```
class Body extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomScrollView(
      slivers: [
        SliverToBoxAdapter(child: SizedBox(height: getProportionateScreenHeight(10))),
        SliverToBoxAdapter(child: ProductHeader()),
        SliverToBoxAdapter(child: SizedBox(height: getProportionateScreenHeight(20))),
        SliverList(
          delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                (context, index) {
              return Product();
            },
            childCount: 1,
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

So `SingleChildScrollView` and `Sliver` widgets greatly slow down the application if there are many elements.

[I attach ascreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayOgV.png)   of how I need the page to look like:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap your list view with a `Container` for a fixed `height` and `width`, so the `listview` will occupy all the spaces inside the `container`, and by this, you will be able to fix the problem you are experiencing,

Alternativel, you can pass `shrinkWrap = true` and `physics = NeverScrollablePhysics()`, to your `listview`

Comment: It turns out that the solution lay on the surface. Wrapped my `ListView.builder` in `Container`, and then another in `Expanded`, and it worked. The alternative method using `shrinkWrap = true` did not work. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my `Product` class in this way:

```
class Product extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetX<ProductController>(
      init: ProductController(),
      builder: (controller) {
        return FutureBuilder<List<ProductsCombined>>(
          future: controller.filterProduct.value,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                    // shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                        ProductCards(
                      // index: index,
                      product: snapshot.data[index],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            } else {
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            }
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

And the `Body` class in this way:

```
class Body extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(height: getProportionateScreenHeight(10)),
          ProductHeader(),
          SizedBox(height: getProportionateScreenHeight(20)),
          Product()
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Only now the search bar is not part of the scroll widget, but it suits me.